# Zuul Https reverse Proxy with Angular 2/4 UI and Keycloak

Tags: angular, reverse-proxy, keycloak, netflix-zuul

My problem is related to a Angular4, Zuul and Keycloak as the title suggests. here is an overview of my project structure

UI(Angular4)
Keycloak(User management)
SpringBoot(Microservices)
Zuul(Gateway/Proxy whatever you want to call it)

So What I want is to keep Zuul as single access point for my application and rest of services stay behind zuul as shown in Image below:

[image: overview of project architecture]

my config looks as follows:

```
...

server:
   port: 8800

   ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: classpath:keystore.jks
    key-store-password: "**********"

zuul:
  routes:
    ui:
      path: /**
      url: http://uiserverurl:8000
    kycloak:
      path: /auth/**
      sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorization
      url: http://keycloakserverurl:9090/auth/
    services: /api/v1/services/**
...
```

I am using something like [this](https://github.com/ebondu/angular2-keycloak) for connecting angular with keycloak, so when user accesses the UI on zuul as https://zuulserverurl:8800/ it takes user to actual UI and which in turns takes user to keycloak login screen but here the form action url is not zuulserverurl as it should be but keycloakserverurl and everything fails at this level.

I don't want to implement separate ssl for keycloak and want to use zuul as reverse proxy for keycloak I tried more than just top results on google but nothing seems to work for me.

I have disabled https required for both master and application realm also in order to try out things but not working.

Any help and guidance is appreciated, please let me know for more details on this.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Have you configured keycloak to work behind a SSL proxy?

Comment: Yes I did, I followed documentation of keycloak as it is, also verified that all the headers are passing through the filter.

Comment: I had many problems while trying to configure keycloak to work behind a zuul proxy. I finally decided to have keycloak and my UI service behind a nginx proxy instead and use zuul for the rest of my application. I even created a github project with my whole case and involved a KC team member. Here you've got my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37329232/zuul-reverse-proxy-with-keycloak-server).

Comment: I already saw your project and post, while looking for solutions, currently I have used a Response filter as solution and I am replacing "keycloakserverurl" with "zuulserverurl". something that makes it work, but I am worried that currently keycloak server url is known but URLs are hardcoded in replaceAll(a,b) function which doesn't looks good as long term solution.